# sending multiple data from one fragment to another fragment

Tags: java, android

In My app..one mainActivity..two fragment like fragment A and FragmentB..
   I Created..And I added two editText in FragmentA..I want to send this         editText data to FramentB..and reuse itin..FragmentB..how to do this...
   I should use interface concept..or..is their any another concept..

```
    public class FragmentA extends Fragment  {
      Button nextt;
       EditText number;

      EditText alpha;
       }
         @Override
         public void onStart() {
          super.onStart();
           fm = ((MainActivity) context).getFragmentManager();
      }

      @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          int viewId = view.getId();
          FragmentTransaction ft;
          ft = fm.beginTransaction();
         FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
          ft.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragmentB);
          ft.addToBackStack(null);
           ft.commit();
     }

     @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view = null;

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

           nextt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Button1);
             nextt.setOnClickListener(this);

            number = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.swTypeE);

           alpha = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numE);
         }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Yo can also use PutExtra Method of bundle for transfer multiple data

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 int viewId = view.getId();
 FragmentTransaction ft;
 ft = fm.beginTransaction();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putInt("yourkey",viewId);
 FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
 fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
 ft.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragmentB);
 ft.addToBackStack(null);
 ft.commit();}
```

Get Value in fragmentB

```
String value = getArguments().getString("yourkey");
```

Comment: for receving data in fargmentB?

Comment: @Kingraj check now

Comment: @Kingraj You have to define key to retrieve data in other fragment through this yo can identify your data

Comment: In logcat its printing yourkey is 21469783